# Apache cache serving partial content 206 responses to requests for the full content

Tags: cache, apache-2.2, plone, mod-cache

We're running Plone 3.3.6 behind Apache 2.2.19 with mod_cache. We've recently noticed that Apache is caching the 206 response to a range request and then serving that partial response when a request for the full resource is made.

What seems to happen:

- some client makes a range request for a resource that is not yet in the cache or is in the cache but has expired
- Apache serves the 206 response correctly
- another client makes a standard request the same resource
- Apache serves the same 206 response to this second client: it should serve the entire response with a 200

This is causing problems with our css on some sites very occasionally

I can replicate this consistently: I wrote a little python script to make a range request.

I don't think we're not doing anything out of the ordinary with our Apache configuration.  We're using reverse proxy configuration to serve pages from Plone.  The Apache configuration relevant to mod_cache is as follows:

```
CacheEnable disk /
CacheDisable /static
CacheDisable /sitemap.xml.gz
CacheDisable /robots.txt
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie

UseCanonicalName On

RequestHeader edit Accept-Encoding ^.*gzip.*$ gzip early
RequestHeader edit Accept-Encoding ^(?!gzip).*$ "" early
```

The [Apache caching guide](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/caching.html) doesn't include 206 responses in the list of status codes the response "must have" for it to be cached.  Is this a bug in Apache or are we doing something wrong in the configuration?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is [apache bug 49113](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=49113) and has been [fixed in the trunk](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc?view=revision&revision=933919) but not in 2.2.19.

Comment: Good catch - the testing that I had done wasn't with back-end content that was responding with a `Cache-Control` or `Expires` header, so I wasn't hitting the flawed logic check.

Comment: We’ve patched Apache and this has resolved the issue.  I’d have thought this regression serious enough to make it into a 2.2.x build but no sign of that happening

Comment: Has this been fixed in Ubuntu Lucid's "apache2.2-bin 2.2.14-5ubuntu8.7" (Nov. 3rd 2011)? Can't find any evidence in changelogs...

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed in Apache 2.2.23.  Upgrade to 2.2.23 and you don't need to patch